# Why can I not hit breakpoints after re-attaching the debugger?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

Here's how I typically debug my ASP.NET app:

- F5 to start app
- CTRL+ALT+D to detach the debugger when I encounter a bug
- Fix bug and rebuild
- CTRL+ALT+P to open process list
- Locate any browser pointing to `http://localhost:50000/`
- Attach the debugger to that process

This has always worked flawlessly in VS2010, but now I can't seem to get this to work properly in VS2013.  After re-attaching, none of my breakpoints are hit because it says no symbols have been loaded.

I am using IIS Express for hosting in my project settings if this makes a difference.  It seems that debugging in VS2013 has somehow changed and I want it to behave like it did in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013, ASP.NET projects now have Edit And Continue enabled by default.  This changes your scenario in 2 ways:

1. You don't need to stop debugging and restart.  In most cases, you can just make the change and continue.
2. Stopping the debugger (or detaching) will kill the IIS Express server process.  You'll need to restart the web app (F5 again) to resume.